# Simple Tab Javascript Sections (not menus)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

This might be the simplest question of the day.

I'm looking for the best answer based on all knowledged across community, not a basic tab effect but one that could be scalable, easy to implement and compliant with standards.

What could be a good and simple (compatible) way to accomplish having different sections with Javascript. I personally prefer jQuery, Mootools or plain Javascript.

When each link is clicked it should open up relationed table row or div, not a hover menu. Section has to stay open after selected on left options.

Any help with resources or direction will be greatly appreciated.

Form will have one common submit button with all selected options.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use a pre-existing plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/VELCe/

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest tab code with no jQuery or other plugins.

Add this function under script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTab(tabNumber) {
      var tabIDs = ["tab1", "tab2"];
      var tabButtonIDs = ["tabButton1", "tabButton2"];
      for (var i = 0; i < tabIDs.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(tabIDs[i]).style.display = (tabNumber == i ? 'block' : 'none');
        document.getElementById(tabButtonIDs[i]).className = (tabNumber == i ? "active" : "");
      }
    }
</script>
```

Add these styles to your css

```
        <style type="text/css">
            #tabContainer 
            {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0 0 5px 0;
                padding: 0;
                clear: both;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
                height: 20px;
                clear: both;
            }
            #tabContainer li
            {
                float:left;
                margin-right: 7px;
                text-align: center;         
            }
            #tabContainer li a
            {
                background-color:transparent;
                display: block;
                height: 20px;
                padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
                background-color: white;
                color: #666;
                width: 80px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .active
            {
                background-color: #DDD !important;
            }
        </style>
```

Add tab buttons

```
    <ul id="tabContainer">
        <li><a class="active" id="tabButton1" onclick="showTab(0)" href="javascript:void(0);">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="tabButton2" onclick="showTab(1)" href="javascript:void(0);">Option 2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Add tab content

```
<div id="tab1">Content 1</div>
<div id="tab2" style="display:none;">Content 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you don't even need any javascript to accomplish this.

Have a look at
http://devinrolsen.com/wp-content/themes/typebased/demos/css/vertical-menu/WORKS.html
for a 100% based css menu.

There is even a generator available
http://purecssmenu.com/

Comment: If clicking has to be involved you would need something like $("#nav > li").click(function(){ $(this).find("ul").show(); });

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not looking to build a hover menu but sections which will display on click of link.

Comment: What is the difference except for the click?